# Getting and Verifying Source of Transaction in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am currently using Fabric together with Composer as a platform to test secure transaction of assets or data whilst keeping validity intact

Right now I'm on a use case where a node sends an asset over to another node, but before that the asset will go through a middle node for some changes before ending with the receiving node. Is there any way for me or the receiving node to verify that this asset came from the first node?

Eg: X intends to send a message to Z, but before that he sends to message to Y, Y simplifies the message and sends it to Z. Is there any way for Z to check that the message originated from X?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the `getCurrentParticipant()` call from within your TP function to verify the identity that submitted the transaction. Does that help?

Comment: Wouldn't that return Y instead of X? Based on my example